# CSS Cascading and !important issue

Tags: css

```
#messageContainer td 
    {
        cursor: pointer;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #2A2A2A;
        padding-bottom: 3px;
        padding-top: 3px;
        background-color: #F0F0F0;
    }

    .messageNew
    {
        background-color: #FFFFFF !important;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<tr replytoid="3" messageid="2700" id="15" class="messageNew">
    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="checkAll"></td>
    <td>Rick Hagar</td>
    <td>asd</td>
    <td>3/14/2012 1:09:04 PM</td>
</tr>
```

I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.  Right now as it stands every single `<td>` has the `#F0F0F0` background color.  And the rows with the class `.messageNew` are not being changed to the background color `#FFFFFF`.

What is even stranger, is if I reverse the colors.  I remove the background color `#F0F0F0` and change `#FFFFFF` it works properly.

The client wanted it changed so new messages now have a white background and the read messages have the `#F0F0F0` background.

I added the `!important` but it doesn't seem do make any difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#messageContainer td` has a higher specificity than `.messageNew` and so will "win". Try: `` `#messageContainer .messageNew td `` (you can omit the `!important`)

Comment: For a more in depth explanation, you can also check out http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/

Comment: @JamesWilson If that worked for you, you may want to accept the answer to resolve the question.

Comment: @steveax sorry it took so long, got distracted and forgot to accept.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Background colours on table cells override those on the rows.

Change your selector to `.messageNew > td`, and you won't need the `!important` anymore.

Comment: Every cell has its own background, which is transparent by default. Setting cell background color removes the transparency. Technically it does not override the row background color; the latter just does not shine through for a cell that has non-transparent background.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're setting the `backgroundColor` on your `tr` with the `messageNew` class, but the first rule sets `backgroundColor` on the `td` inside the `tr`, which will override the `tr`s color even with `!important`.